# How to Right-click in Chrome Remote Desktop?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I want to right-click in host OS Windows 8.1 using [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.chromeremotedesktop) app. How to do this?

Android platform: Nexus 7 (Android 4.4.2 KitKat) - No OTG Mouse attached

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can right click by using 2 fingers at once. This is the same for Microsoft's RD Client app for Android as well.

Comment: It's really too bad that MS didn't write to handle pressing the S-Pen button to be a right click.  :(

Comment: I have a Note 3. I feel your pain.

Comment: Well, I just tweeted that suggestion to MS Support... who knows, maybe we'll see it in an update! {fingers crossed}  Though I won't hold my breath.

Comment: It's better if you hold your finger at one spot that it right clicks.